# Contextual Filters in a 'Tree-style' View

Tags: 7, views

I am using the [Views Tree Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) which allows me to create a View that illustrates parent-child relationships.

My 'associations' go like this:

I have 3 content types which entity-reference each to a single direction.

- A ***Sub task*** has an EntityReference field pointing to a ***Main
  Task*** and a ***Main Task*** has an EntityReference field pointing
  to a ***Project***.

  ```
    Subtask -> Main Task -> Project. (associations are done with EntityReference fields)
  ```

Now I'd like to embed this view as a block within a given ***Project***'s page. Naturally I use a *Contextual Filter* that uses the *ContentID from Url* setting.

I thought this would allow me to view within that ***Project***'s page the ***Main Tasks*** and ***Sub Tasks*** that belong to it, but since only the ***Main Tasks*** are *directly connected* with the Project itself only the Main Tasks are shown.

---

## The question:

Is there any way to bring the ***Subtasks***(which belong to the ***Main Tasks*** that belong to the given ***Project***) to show as well?

---

## Summary of my project

To sum this up:

I have 3 content types

- Project
- Main Task
- Sub Task

---

- A Subtask entity references a Main Task and this in turn entity
  references a Project
- I use the [Views Tree module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) to list the Main Tasks and the Subtasks
  below each Main Task(in a 'tree-style' view
- I want to show this view with the appropriate Main Tasks/Subtasks
  inside each Project page.
- I use the [Views Tree module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) to construct parent-child relationship
  Views

Answer (score 0):

I found a rather clean and intuitive solution, **however** I am very interested in other, more straightforward answers if they exist.

---

I created a new *[Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field)*, called parent_project_computed field which:

- calculates the parent-project based on the **parent_main_task**
  field(which is entity reference) if it's a **Sub Task** content type
- calculates(basically just copies) the **parent_project** field if
  it's a **Main Task** content type

This way both the **Main Task** and **Sub task** have a field which stores the nid value of the **Parent Project**. Then I use a contextual filter based on this new parent_project_computed field and both content types match this filter so they show up in the results just fine.

This is the PHP I wrote within this new computed field:

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = null; //initial value null, should get overwritten in IF's below

//if field_parent_project exists just copy it's value
if (array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_parent_project')))) {
   $entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_parent_project')));
}

// if 'field_main_task' exists get it's value, load the node and get the E-R value within it
if (array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_main_task')))) {
    $nid = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_main_task')));
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $info = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_parent_project');
    $entity_field[0]['value'] =$info[0];//ER fields store data in array, since this is a single value ER field it always sits at position '0'
}

//Note: E-R value means Entity Reference value.
```

If the PHP code can be made more, err bulletproof, I'd appreciate a comment below. 
Thanks.

**Update:**

On saving each **Task** you need a post-save custom hook to reload and resave all the **Subtasks** in order to update their 'Parent Project' computed field which has now changed. We've used [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action) which provides some nice additional post-save hooks and some more.